# Linux server, laravel problem with configuration

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, server, apache2

currently I am setting up a new server based on linux, installed apache2, MySQL, phpmyadmin and etc.

Installed my Laravel project with git, and all seems to be working well except some request that are made to the server.

Currently my folder structure for /var/www/ is:

```
-/var/www
--- /home
--- /laravel
```

When the user accesses the server through http://server.xxxxxxx.com/ is redirected to /home where there is a landing page, basically a face for the web-app.

When the user goes to `http://server.xxxxxxx.com/erp/`, he is redirected to the `/laravel/public` directory.

All loads well, the application is running perfectly, but AJAX request fail everywhere.

Every AJAX request ends with an error. For example:

> The requested URL /pie-data was not found on this server

I have tried all the things I could find for this URL problem in the net, but nothing really seemed to have helped. One thing that helped, was to edit the apache config, where I had made an Alias for "/" to redirect to `/var/www/laravel/public` folder. But this is not a solution for me, because, that way I cannot access phpmyadmin.

Routes in my web.php file:

```php
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/set-warehouse', 'DashboardController@setWarehouse');
Route::get('/pie-data', 'DashboardController@getDonutData');
Route::get('/mechanics-load', 'DashboardController@mechanicsWorkLoad');
Route::get('/monthly-load', 'DashboardController@monthlyLoad');
Route::get('/change-date-mechanics', 'DashboardController@changeMechanicsWorkLoad');
```

One of the AJAX requests:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/pie-data',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.type === 'success') {
            pieChart.Doughnut(data.data, pieOptions);
            $('canvas[id="pieChart"]').empty().after(data.legend);
        }
    },
});
```

000-default.conf file:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName server.xxxxxxx.com
    ServerAdmin somemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/home/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /erp "/var/www/laravel/public/"

    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The .htaccess file is standard for Laravel 5.8, it is not changed at all.

When the user is in http://server.xxxxxxx.com/erp/dashboard, 4 or more AJAX calls are made, but not to http://server.xxxxxxx.com/erp/pie-chart (which will return a JSON for the plugin), but are made to http://server.xxxxxxx.com/pie-chart. Is there any way to fix this functionality, without changing the folder structure? Thank you in advance for the replies!

Comment: Complete Instructions to Setup a Linux server with NGINX, MySQL and PHP: https://github.com/akshaykhale1992/nginx-php-mysql-setup

Comment: This is not helping me in any way. I have already installed and configured everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is attempting to GET /pie-data, more specifically (/var/www/home/pie-data) when it looks like you want /erp/pie-data

Comment: Yes, I want it to /erp/pie-data